# How to remove duplicates data from array

Tags: arrays, swift, uitableview, for-loop

Im implementing followes and following feature in my app . Im storing a data on firestore after fetching data from Firestone and passing into the function array data gets multiplied.

```
FirebaseReference(.Users).getDocuments{(snapshot, error) in
    if error != nil {
        print("Document Error: ", error!)
    } else {
        if let doc = snapshot, doc.isEmpty == false {
            print("User Document is present.")
            let desc = doc.documents
            for item in desc
            {
                
                let user = item.data()
                let name = user["name"] as! String
                let uid = user["userID"] as! String
                let img = user["imgUrl"] as? String
                

                FirebaseReference(.Users).document(FUser.currentUser()?.userID ?? "").collection("Following").getDocuments{(snapshot1,error) in
                    if error != nil {
                        print("Document Error: ", error!)
                    } else {
                        if let doc1 = snapshot1, doc1.isEmpty == false {
                            let data = doc1.documents
                            
                            var followingid = ""
                            for newitem in data
                            {
                                
                                let value = newitem.data()
                                followingid = value["followedToUserId"] as? String ?? ""
                                self.getPostData(name: name, uid: uid, img: img ?? "",followingId: followingid )
                            }
                            
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            self.getPostData(name: name, uid: uid, img: img ?? "",followingId:"NA")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            print("User Document is not present.")
        }
    }
}
```

IF Im passing data in this function self.getPostData() inside for loop my data gets multiplied.Please anyone can help me out from this.

Thank You

Comment: Is the followingId multiply , others (name,uid,,mage) is not or all the datas are multiplied? Better to see your array to make a clear answer to us

Comment: Instead of removing duplicates why not make sure duplicates aren’t added?

Comment: In second for duplicates are adding if I'm writing function outside the for loop than duplicates are not adding

Comment: @AnandVishwakarma what should be your `final data structure`? 
Can you add function definition of `getPostData`

Comment: So the problem is with the function getPostData then?

Answer (score 0):

use set

```
let a = ["hai","hai","hello"]
let unique = Array(Set(a))
print(unique)

output should -> ["hai", "hello"]

NB: result won't be in order, if you want remove a duplicate model , model just needs to confirm the class Hashable and the process and result would be same

struct User: Hashable{
var name: String
var age: Int
}

let a = [User(name: "a",age:15), User(name: "a",age:15),User(name: "b",age:30)]
let unique = Array(Set(a))
print(unique)


result -> [main.User(name: "a", age: 15), main.User(name: "b", age: 30)]
```